# Allow only one selection per column and row in a webpage's grid of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, radio-button

I have a grid of 5x5 radio buttons, with the each row being a "group" (sharing the same name).

[image]

I want to make it so that when A3 is selected, B3 C3 D3 and E3 can not be selected and for example if B4 is selected no other button in row B or column 4 can be selected.

[image]

I have tried using multiple names, but as far as my testing goes this doesn't work. I have tried to find a solution with Jquery but nothing seems to work. Is the only way to achieve this using a bit of complex JavaScript?

Comment: Show some code what you have tried and make a fiddle...

Comment: Can you share the code currently you have so that we can play with it..? a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be even better

Comment: @aldanux Here you go : http://jsfiddle.net/gLCV3/

Comment: You will notice there is no JS trying to attempt this, because as I said in the question before I sit down and spend ages writing that I want to make sure I haven't missed a much simpler way

Comment: I suppose, that each radio for one column has the same value, is it?

Comment: @falcon Yes it is. The value would be 1,2,3,4 or 5...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easiest done by adding classes to each radio button, one for column and one for row. As a radio button is checked, all that needs to be done is to disable those with one matching class (i.e. matching row or column).

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    var classes = $(this).prop('class').split(' ');
    for (i in classes)
        $('.'+classes[i]).attr('disabled', true);
});
```

[A JSFiddle that demonstrates the technique.](http://jsfiddle.net/fgVS9/)

Comment: Perfect. If I could +2 for the JSFiddle I would

Comment: Note that restricting the radio buttons this way makes it impossible to revert a choice without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 2):

Rows are handled automatically if they have the same name.
Disabling other radio-buttons prevents you from changing your mind. I'd consider deselcting conflicting Radiobuttons.

```
$(".radiobutton").on("change", function(ev) {
    var clicked = $(ev.target);
    $(".radiobutton[data-col=" + clicked.data("col") + "]").attr("checked", false);
    clicked.attr("checked", true);
});
```

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/wCCW9/)